# Highlighting partcular word in a sentence in a input box when i type with react

Tags: reactjs

I want to highlight a particular word in a sentence when i'm typing in the text-input box how can i do it with react & tailwind without using dangerousinnerhtml

I apologize for the confusion. If you want to display the highlighted text within the input box and avoid the error, you can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property to render the HTML content. Here's the updated code:

```
// src/App.js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Focus on the input when the component mounts
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }, []);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;

    // Highlight only the word "tomato" in red
    const highlightedText = value.replace(/\btomato\b/gi, (match) => `<span class="text-red-500">${match}</span>`);

    // Set the input text with HTML tags for rendering
    setInputText(highlightedText);
  };

  return (
    <div className="p-4">
      <label className="block mb-2">Type up to 64 characters:</label>
      <div
        ref={inputRef}
        contentEditable
        maxLength={64}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: inputText }}
        onInput={handleInputChange}
        className="border p-2"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you looking for how you can highlight a specific word in the `<input/>` box and that too without using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Is that correct ?

Comment: Mrinmay Santra yes